# If value contains string, then set another column value

Tags: python, regex, parsing, pandas

I have a dataframe in Pandas with a column called 'Campaign' it has values like this:

"UK-Sample-Car Rental-Car-Broad-MatchPost"

I need to be able to pull out that the string contains the word 'Car Rental' and set another Product column to be 'CAR'.  The hyphen is not always separating out the word Car, so finding the string this way isn't an possible.

How can I achieve this in Pandas/Python?

Comment: You're going to have to post representative data as the answer entirely depends on your data composition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pandas as some sweet string functions you can use

for example, like this:

```
df['vehicle'] = df.Campaign.str.extract('(Car).Rental').str.upper()
```

This sets the column vehicle to what is contained inside the parenthesis of the regular expression given to the [`extract function`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html).

Also the [`str.upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/text.html) makes it uppercase

#### Extra Bonus:

If you want to assign vehicle something that is not in the original string, you have to take a few more steps, but we still use the string functions This time [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.contains.html) .

```
is_motorcycle = df.Campaign.str.contains('Motorcycle')
df['vehicle'] = pd.Series(["MC"] * len(df)) * is_motorcycle
```

The second line here creates a series of "MC" strings, then masks it on the entries which we found to be motorcycles.

If you want to combine multiple, I suggest you use the map function:

```
vehicle_list = df.Campaign.str.extract('(Car).Rental|(Motorcycle)|(Hotel)|(.*)')
vehicle = vehicle_list.apply(lambda x: x[x.last_valid_index()], axis=1)
df['vehicle'] = vehicle.map({'Car':'Car campaign', 'Hotel':'Hotel campaign'})
```

This first extracts the data into a list of options per line. The cases are split by | and the last one is just a catch-all which is needed for the [`Series.apply function`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) below.
The [`Series.map function`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) is pretty straight forward, if the captured data is 'Car', we set 'Car campaign', and 'Hotel' we set 'Hotel campaign' etc.

Comment: that's incredible, thanks!  what if I wanted to call it something custom?  for example if the string "Hotel" is found, call it "HTL"?

Comment: @JonathanKennedy Added some more to the answer.